# How to get Slope (Beta) only from stats.linregress using a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy.stats

I'm trying to pull just the slope (beta) from running stats.linregress on a DataFrame.

For some reason I'm getting a blank value just for slope i.e. using[0] in the loop but all the values if I use something like [0:3]. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
      
     beta_df[i] = pd.DataFrame(columns = all_perf_time_series.columns)
    
     for i in all_perf_time_series:
               
        beta_df = stats.linregress(all_perf_time_series['Benchmark'],all_perf_time_series[i])[0]
```

This is the blank result I get:

[image]

But if I run this code:

```
      
     beta_df[i] = pd.DataFrame(columns = all_perf_time_series.columns)
    
     for i in all_perf_time_series:
                      
        beta_df = stats.linregress(all_perf_time_series['Benchmark'],all_perf_time_series[i])[0:3]
```

I get this result:

[image]

Comment: The results you are showing are obtained by printing beta_df after the operations?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: It's strange because beta_df in the first example should be a float, i.e. the first value of the output, while in the second example should be a list of floats, i.e. the first three values of the output; not a DataFrame